# How to layout images in 3 columns

Tags: html, css, image

How to place image like that (html,css):
[image]

I try:

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/666" height="300" width="200"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/333" height="150" width="100" align="top"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f2f" height="150" width="100" align="top"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ee3" height="150" width="100"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/532" height="150" width="100"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code request system. Try to do it yourself and post your code, then you will get help.

Comment: Would be happy to help you. But your question should adhere to the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'sorry. I try but no insert in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)**.

CSS

```
#container-outer {
    display: flex;
}

.container-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container-outer">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/666" height="300" width="200">
    <div class="container-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/333" height="150" width="100">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f2f" height="150" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="container-inner">
       <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ee3" height="150" width="100">
       <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/532" height="150" width="100">
    </div>
</div><!-- end #container-outer -->
```

DEMO (image dimensions fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/3wbme70k/
DEMO (responsive): http://jsfiddle.net/3wbme70k/1/

Comment: Thx. But this is not responsive...

Comment: Flexbox is completely responsive. But I'm using your HTML, which sets a fixed width and height for the images. You can remove those fixed values and use relative values (like percentages) in CSS.

Comment: I use Your code. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've added a responsive demo version to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use float to do this. 
As an exception here is the code:

```
<div style="float:left;background:red;height: 100px;width:50%;">1</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 50px;width:25%;background:blue;">2</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 50px;width:25%;background:green;">3</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 50px;width:25%;background:yellow;">4</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 50px;width:25%;background:grey;">5</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/webbis12/ko5p2gnc/

In the future please follow the guidelines.

**Edit:** I checked your code. Please use CSS-Styles. Float breaks if there is not enough space.

Comment: Thanks.
Look: https://jsfiddle.net/ko5p2gnc/1/ if zoom that is empty area (padding/margin?)

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. The div has a height of 154px and the image has a height of 150px. So that might cause a margin. You have to set the height of the div. And do not use width and height attribute for the image. Use CSS.